# Is libcudpp.so missing from CUDA 7.0?

Tags: cuda, jcuda, cudpp

I am using jCuda and tried to compile and run one of its examples(JCudppHashSample) available on [jcuda](http://jcuda.org) on Ubuntu 14.04 with CUDA 7.0.

But at compile time the library jcudpp says that there is no libcudpp available. And I am wondering is it missing from cuda sdk or not?

I don't like the idea of getting its source and make it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not part of the CUDA toolkit or CUDA SDK.

You will have to get it from its [source](http://cudpp.github.io/).

The JCuda pages [you linked](http://jcuda.org/jcuda/jcudpp/JCudpp.html) indicate:

> JCudpp is only a Java binding for CUDPP. That means, in order to use JCudpp, you need the CUDPP library. This library can be compiled from the source code that is available at the CUDPP home page

Comment: hmm.. I think this is it. But its wierd.. you know that CUFTT or CURAND or CUSOLVER that jCuda has a bundle for them, are part of the SDK already.. I thought this one have to be, too.